# In Mediawiki's tinymce extension, how to enable/disable buttons?

Tags: tinymce, mediawiki

In https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TinyMCE, there a section with Toolbar buttons including a Citation/reference button which looks like this:

[image]

Furthermore, it says: "Depending on configuration, some or all of these buttons may be shown".

It is not clear however how to enable/disable specific buttons in LocalSettings.php.

In the https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TinyMCE/Configuration page, there are instructions on how to add buttons to toolbars, and based on that I have added this to my LocalSettings.php:

```
wfLoadExtension( "TinyMCE" );
$wgTinyMCEEnabled = true;
$wgTinyMCESettings = [
  ".tox-tinymce" => [
    "toolbar+" => " | citation",
  ],
];
```

.tox-tinymce being the selector for the text box where TinyMCE applies.

The citation button does not appear currently, and before I debug, I'd like to know (1) if I am on the right track, and (2) how can i know the machine name of a button (I assume it's citation, but maybe it's "footnote" or "cite", it is not clear where to find the mapping of machine names to buttons).

Comment: Have you done Ctrl + F5 on the edit page?

Comment: Yes I have, I think however that citation is not the correct machine name for this button. I have not found a resource which lists all the available machine names for buttons, so I can't find what the correct machine name for the citation button is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through the [mediawiki-extensions-TinyMCE-master](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-TinyMCE)

Inside custom plugin directory mediawiki/plugins I saw 12 custom plugins.

I have opened one by one plugin code I observed only 3 plugins wikitext, wikitoggle , wikiupload are loaded in tinymce plugin manager. Ex:-

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('wikitoggle', wikitoggle);
```

I could enable these buttons directly in load-extensions.php.

```
wfLoadExtension( "TinyMCE" );
$wgTinyMCEEnabled = true;


$wgTinyMCESettings = [
  "#wpTextbox1" => [
    "toolbar" => 'wikitext wikitoggle wikiupload',
  ],
];
```

I saw [wikireference](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-TinyMCE/blob/master/custom_plugins/mediawiki/plugins/mw_wikireference/plugin.js) code at the end it has plugin function defination.

```
function Plugin () {
    // only load plugin if the 'cite' extension is enabled
    // in the wiki, eg, if 'ref' tag is in extension tag list
    if ( extensionTagsList.split('|').indexOf('ref') > -1 ) {
        pluginManager.add('wikireference', function (editor) {
            registerCommands( editor );
            registerButtons( editor );
            setup( editor );
        });
    }
}

Plugin();



// only load plugin if the 'cite' extension is enabled
// in the wiki, eg, if 'ref' tag is in extension tag list
```

from the plugin method comments I could figure it out how to load reference and comment buttons.

1. first we need to download and install Cite extension plugin

   echo 'Downloading and installing Cite'

   echo 'See [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite#Installation'](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite#Installation%27)

   curl -O -L https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Cite/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

   unzip master.zip

   rm master.zip

   mv mediawiki-extensions-Cite-master extensions/Cite
2. Enable reference and comment button in load-extensions.php

   [
        "toolbar" => 'reference comment',
      ],
    ];

Comment: You also have to wfLoadExtension( "Cite" ); in load-extensions.php